# Latest Value for each day - Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Anyone can help to put this into a Laravel Eloquent statement ?
where timestamp = unix timestamp

```
SELECT max(timestamp) ,value FROM `forex` group by FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp,'%Y%m%d' )
```

Comment: What is the issue that you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DB::table('forex')
     ->selectRaw('MAX(forex.TIMESTAMP), forex.value')
     ->groupByRaw('forex.TIMESTAMP, "%Y%m%d"')
     ->get();
```

Comment: It didnt work due to this 'forex.TIMESTAMP, "%Y%m%d"'
Without the FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp,'%Y%m%d' )

Comment: replace the groupbyRaw with this solved it 
->groupBy(DB::raw("FROM_UNIXTIME(forex.timestamp,'%Y%m%d')"))